# Drools issue at runtime

Tags: java, spring, drools, kie

I'm using spring 3.5 + drools 6.3.0

I have a multi-module project, where module A contains the drools definitions as well as the drl resources, this module is used by module B which has the main class.

in development mode every thing works fine, but when the package is built and deployed It keeps throwing this exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.util.CDIHelper$BeanCreatorHolder
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.util.CDIHelper.wireListnersAndWIHs(CDIHelper.java:45) ~[drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:594) ~[drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
>       at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:558) ~[drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar:6.3.0.Final]
>       at fr.cerner.jango.ui.bi.PostProcessItemsService.getKieSession(PostProcessItemsService.java:49) ~[fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>   at fr.cerner.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.p2p.handler.ItemsPersistenceProcessor.process(ItemsPersistenceProcessor.java:37) ~[fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at fr.cerner.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.p2p.handler.PersistenceQueue.flush(PersistenceQueue.java:44) ~[fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at fr.cerner.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.p2p.aop.ItemEventsAspect.modify(ItemEventsAspect.java:67) ~[fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at fr.cerner.jango.ui.AMOComposite.handleSaveChanges(AMOComposite.java:474) [fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at fr.cerner.jango.ui.AMOComposite.access$3(AMOComposite.java:446) [fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at fr.cerner.jango.ui.AMOComposite$5.widgetSelected(AMOComposite.java:320) [fr.cerner.questionnaire-1.7.0-20151116.111758-41.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]
>       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761) [org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86-3.103.2-SDK-4.4.2.jar:na]

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:kie="http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring http://drools.org/schema/kie-spring-2.0.0.xsd">
<kie:kmodule id="questionnaireBI" >

    <kie:kbase name="pre-process" packages="rules.preprocess"
        equalsBehavior="equality"> 
        <kie:ksession name="preProcessKSession"   type="stateful"
            scope="prototype">
            <kie:consoleLogger />
        </kie:ksession>
    </kie:kbase>
   .... other kbase definition omitted 
<!--pour les @KSession etc .. annotation -->
<bean id="kiePostProcessor"
    class="org.kie.spring.annotations.KModuleAnnotationPostProcessor" />

<bean id="handleChangeEventService" class="fr.cerner.jango.ui.bi.ExonerationService" />
<bean id="checkItemsService" class="fr.cerner.jango.ui.bi.CheckItemsService" />
<bean id="itemsValidationService" class="fr.cerner.jango.ui.bi.ItemsValidationService" />
<bean id="postProcessItemsService" class="fr.cerner.jango.ui.bi.PostProcessItemsService" />

</beans>
```

and this is my imports:

```
<!-- drools engine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-verifier</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**update**

Here is how do I initialize the KSession ( tried injection as well )

```
// placed here to early initialize the engine
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    factory = org.kie.api.KieServices.Factory.get();
    container = factory.getKieClasspathContainer();
    //
    // container = factory.getKieClasspathContainer(
    // ProjectClassLoader.getClassLoader(CDIHelper.class.getClassLoader(),
    // ExonerationService.class, true));

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            KieSession kieSession = getKieSession();
            kieSession.dispose();
        }
    });
}

private KieSession getKieSession() {
    return container.newKieSession("preProcessKSession");// context.getBean("preProcessKSession",
                                                            // KieSession.class);
}
```

any idea or leads are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: thank you, I updated the stacktrace

Comment: Are you using an app/servlet container to deploy your application? Which one? The exception you are getting is hiding the real one I think. 

Any change you can debug CDIHelper class? I would pay special attention to the method `lookupBeanManager` from `CDIHelper.BeanCreatorHolder`: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/6.3.x/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/kie/util/CDIHelper.java#L144

Comment: No in fact it's a desktop app, I have no app/servlet container, but here I updated the FULL stacktrace. thank you agin

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.drools.compiler.kie.util.CDIHelper$BeanCreatorHolder at

Above means most likely you have mixed wrong versions of jars on your class path.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out :

In fact, in my dev environment I have an IBM (`com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient`) lib for websphere ( the application can be deployed in a container depending on client ), despite I have added a profile but this dependency is still my eclipse.

In the deliverable we have set a jndi context to an Object from this lib, when the engine starts it tries to lookup for the `BeanManager` ( Thanks for @Esteban Aliverti  for pointing me there ) it starts the context and an exception is thrown since the jar is filtered by a profile.